# OpenVPN or IPtables for split tunnel control?

Tags: routing, openvpn, tunneling, ufw

I have been plugging away but not luck, but from what I understand what I am trying to split tunnel.  I have a VPN in place (and working) where all traffic from my LAN heads out to the internet via the VPN. My challenge is that I would like to have two hosts within the LAN go to the internet directly (i.e. a TV that has Netflix, and an Xbox) and bypass the VPN in place.

I have tried making changes to my OpenVPN config but they haven't worked (currently commented out in the below files), and I suspect it stems from my routing table being an issue.

Can anyone shed light on where I'm going wrong?

**Interfaces**

```
Internal/LAN: enp4s0
Internet: enp5s0
VPN: tun0
```

**OpenVPN Config**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 45.248.79.198 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
explicit-exit-notify 3
remote-cert-tls server
#route-nopull 
#route 192.168.1.236 255.255.255.255
#push "route 192.168.1.241 255.255.255.0 default"
#push "route 192.168.1.220 255.255.0.0 gateway"
auth-user-pass pw.txt
comp-lzo
verb 1
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
disable-occ
script-security 2
#route-noexec
```

**Route Table (VPN enabled)**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
10.8.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
45.248.79.198   _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp5s0
128.0.0.0       10.8.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
```

**Route Table (VPN disabled)**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
```

**UFW Rule (to get LAN traffic to VPN)**

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Just 2 quick ideas FWIW: 1. [OpenVPN has a forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/) that might give you access to more SMEs, and 2. [OPNsense](https://opnsense.org/) on a 3-NIC box might make your chore easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on OPNsense, but that would seem to mean replacing Ubuntu as my OS which I am not as keen on doing as it runs a number of services for me.  That said I'll hit up the OpenVPN forum and see what they say there.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Closing this one out.

From talking to my VPN provider you can't edit the server.conf file as it sits on their side.  So the resolution for a request like this is not within the OpenVPN settings, but in your route table instead.